# Maintaining active of button until another button is clicked

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've created a set of buttons using bootstrap:
[image]

As seen on the image, I've set the "Europe" button as a default active. If I click the other buttons, the active button will switch, so that works perfectly. However, if I have a button active, then click somewhere else on the page (not buttons), it will also deactivate the current button. How do I make a button stay active, until another button is clicked?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    <title>PUBG Comparison Tool</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="text-center">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" autofocus class="btn btn-default">Europe</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Korea/Japan</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">North America</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Oceania</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Kakao</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">South-East Asia</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">South America</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Asia</button>
      </div>
    <br>
    <img src="images/PUBG-lg.png" alt="PUBGLogo" width="30%" height="30%">
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.btn-group {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn-group button:focus {
    outline:none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: lightslategray;
}

.btn-group button:active {
    background-color: lightslategray;
}

body {
    background-image: url(images/pubgbg.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.text-center > img {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bootstrap 4 you can use btn-group-toggle:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

This should solve your problem because it will use this button like checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to toggle a class "active"/"clicked" or whatever you prefer on a button via jQuery when it is clicked, like so:

```
$('.menu-buttons').bind('click', function() {
  var buttons = $('.menu-buttons');
  buttons.toggleClass("active");
});
```

and then add the prefered styling to the "active" class:

```
.active{
  background-color: lightslategray;
}
```

Comment: jquery was not tagged .. even JS was not tagged